My C#/Winforms app doesn't show up at startup
I developed a start up for my C# app using Visual Studio (means: that if the PC turned on, the app will run). But if I turn on my PC, it will not show. I tried to check the registry keys (for this we need to press win + r, and type regedit, and paste the path Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) and my app is still there. I also tried to create a new project and set it to startup but it still the same, And I tried to see the "Startup" section in "Task Manager" and my app are still there, So why didn't it show up when I started the PC?
This is the source code for the new project to test:
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            reg.SetValue("MyApdp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
        }
    }
}

Thanks a lot :)
I expect to see my app showing up at startup.
for declarations: yes it shows up in the "Startup" tab in "Task Manager" and also it is enabled but in the same tab in "startup impact" where you can see how it impact the start up time example (high low), but in my app it says "not measure" and if I hover my mouse over it, says "restart your PC" to get the impact but I restarted it and nothing happened.
yes my app started when I launched it manually and it does launch if I remove the registry "OpenSubKey" and "SetValue" lines from my app but it does not launch in the startup.

I suspect that this is the result of Registry virtualisation, so I suggest that you look into that.

Does your app launch at all when started manually?  Does the app launch if you remove the Registry OpenSubKey and SetValue lines from your app?

Does it show up in the "Startup" tab in Task Manager? Is it "Enabled"?

// Gerry Schmitz
yes it shows up in the startup tab in task manager and also it enabled but in the same tab in startup impact were you can see how it impact the start up time example (high low) , but in my app it says not measure and if i hover my mouse over it , says restart you pc to get the impact but i restarted it up

// Wyck
yes my app started when i  launched it manually and it does launch if i remove the registry OpenSubKey and SetValue lines from your app but it does not launch in the startup

Have you checked if there is any other process that may affect modifying the registry value when your PC start up?

To solve the problem, it is better to pay attention to the following:
1- In the question, it is said that you expect "if the PC turned on the app will run", but it appears from your code that you set it to run in the "Startup" registry key of the current user.
If you expect to see the program running when the computer is turned on and before logging in, like antivirus programs, you should design it as a Windows service. Services can be run automatically when starting the computer and with a pre-set user access (system or user account, etc.).
2- If you mean that you want it to run after logging in, also as another method, instead of setting the path of the program in the registry, you can also put the program shortcut in the desired user's "Startup" folder (in the path below), of course, "Username" should be replaced with the name of the desired user to run the program after logging in (for Windows 10 and 11).
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

3- Using "Application.ExecutablePath.ToString()" in the application itself to set the automatic execution of the application is not an ideal method. Because, for example, if you build the program in "Debug" mode or if you build it as "Relerase", different paths will be set. It is better to transfer the final files of the program to a  folder inside "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)" and place its path in the registry, or set the executable program shortcut in the "Startup" folder,
4- If you want to do it more professional, it's better to use the installer creator software.
